Volleyball serve trajectory
When I was in high school, I played Volleyball in a regional team.
First we learned that the underhand serve is basically useless.
Then we learned the over-head hit. Then we moved to the run-and-jump-and-hit serve, with a downward spin.
It turned out that this was pretty cool to do, but very predictable for the other team, to see where the ball will come down (I am getting to the question in a minute).
So the newest way to serve was, to hit the ball with a flat palm straight over the net. No spin.
Now to the question: The ball would fly in a kind of swerving left-to-right way. Not just straight. Possibly up-and-down too. I am not sure.
So what I think is, when you hit the ball, it deforms. First in the straight direction, then because of the elasticity, deforms in the left-to-right direction (and so on).
So, the ball to air friction / drag is changing and causing some kind of oscillation.
What are your thoughts?

A ball moving through the air is going to create lift and turbulence.  When rotating, these are normally stable.
When the ball is not rotating, the lift that is created can oscillate from one side to the other unpredictably.   It happens even on smooth spheres and does not require any deformation to occur.  APS Paper talk

What you describe reminds me of a particular pitch in baseball that is called a 'floater'. The more common name is 'knuckleball'
In order to behave as a floater the ball must be thrown without spin, which I gather is hard to do.
A floater tends to be way less predictable than any pitch thrown with spin.

Here is my guess:
When the ball is spinning the air flow around the ball is consistent; the spinning ball will drag the air.
It would appear that in the case of a floater the direction of the air around the ball is erratic. The direction in which the air is flowing around the ball may drift, or even flip from one direction to the opposite way, causing change in the direction in which the ball is going.

It is not easy to calculate a trajectory that is affected by air. If you did, it would be hard to make your serve match your calculations. For the purpose of sports, trajectories are best learned by experience and practice.
Small air currents and small imperfections in the ball have large effects, especially when there is no spin. When there is spin, the result can still be surprising. You might find this interesting. Backspin Basketball Flies Off Dam
